# Rank column values in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I know that this row is wrong:

```
ws.Cells(i, "D").Resize(39).Rank_Eq(2, "2:40", 1) = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

I want to rank the whole column D in column E. The numbers should be "grouped" in 39 numbers.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the name of the sheet

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row  'Find the last row in column D
For i = 2 To lrow Step 39 'Loop every group (group of 13 rows) in column D
    ws.Cells(i, "D").Resize(39).Rank_Eq(2, "2:40", 1) = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code will do what you want. Please pay attention to the constants at the top which you have to set to suit your needs.

1. `FirstDataRow` - your data seem to start in row 2. So, don't change.
2. `GroupSize` - I tested groups of 3 rows. I think you want groups of 39 rows.  Change it.
3. `TgtClm` - Your data are in column 4 (column D). No need to change now.

Once you have set these 3 constants the code is ready to run. Please try it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ' 034

    Const FirstDataRow  As Long = 2
    Const GroupSize     As Long = 3             ' change to suit
    Const TgtClm        As Long = 4             ' Target Column (4 = column D)
                                                ' the output will be in the adjacent column

    Dim Ws              As Worksheet
    Dim Rng             As Range                ' cells in one group
    Dim lRow            As Long                 ' last used row
    Dim Rstart          As Long                 ' first row in group range
    Dim Rend            As Long                 ' last row in group range


    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")            'Set the name of the sheet
    lRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, TgtClm).End(xlUp).Row    'Find the last used row

    Rstart = FirstDataRow
    Do
        Rend = Application.Min(Rstart + GroupSize - 1, lRow)
        With Ws
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Rstart, TgtClm), .Cells(Rend, TgtClm))
        End With

        Rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=RANK(" & Rng.Cells(1).Address(0, 1) & _
                                          "," & Rng.Address & ",0)"
        Rstart = Rend + 1
        If Rstart > lRow Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note that the final 0 in the RANK formula (here: `& Rng.Address & ",0)"`) instructs to rank in desscending order, meaning the highest number will get the lowest rank (100 = 1, 90 = 2 etc). Change to `1` if you need the opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this topic so well, but on the webpage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.rank_eq

Is written that expression.Rank_Eq (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3), and the 
expression A variable that represents a WorksheetFunction object.
In your code it looks like a Range object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don´t get it anyway. Do you know whats wrong with this row. " ws.Cells(i, "D").Resize(39).Rank.Eq(2, "2:40", 1) = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)"?

Comment: Would you like to put the values in the range or the worksheet functions?